# EF Code First Auto generate column ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I was wondering if it where at all possible to have a Key that auto generated like this:

- CBE_2012_1
- CBE_2012_2
- CBE_2012_3
- CBE_2013_1
- CBE_2013_2
- CBA_2013_1
- CBA_2013_2
- CBC_2013_1

I now have this in my class, with ID is Id with autonumbering:

```
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

But I would like to have this with Number being the KEY & format: Code_Year_Id:

```
    [Key]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Can anybody help me with this? 
Or does anybody have helpfull documentation that can provide me with a decent solution?

Before I save a new item I could just create a number myself (In code), but there could be 2 people saving a new item @ the same time and I do not want an exception on duplicate key..

Zarkos

Comment: The key collision problem is essentially unfixable if you want to have natural keys and they can collide.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, using a meaningful value for a key is a bad idea.  You will be much better off using a sequential value who's only purpose is to ensure referential integrity.  If for not other reason than: if your key is not sequential, you are going to get a lot of fragmentation on your index as you insert new records.

If you do want to be sure that you get a unique value, you could create a SQL table that holds your last value, and then a UDF or sproc that takes the current value in that table, increments it to the next value and then returns that value.